# DJI Matrice compatibility with ROS

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all!

Has anyone successfully integrated ROS (kinetic or indigo) into DJI Matrice series [200](http://www.dji.com/matrice-200-series) and 600?
They look very proprietary & Windows / Mac oriented but the platforms sure are sweet. Especially for higher level decision experiments.
I am aware they have both an onboard SDK and a ROS node. However, the buzz in my corner of the world is that the SDK is poorly documented and unstable and that the ROS node is quite limited. What I am asking is if anyone has hands-on experience.

Thanks in advance for sharing your experience.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273484/dji-matrice-compatibility-with-ros/) by [kotoko](https://answers.ros.org/users/27417/kotoko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2017-10-19

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mickboe1](https://answers.ros.org/users/32263/mickboe1/) on 2017-10-19**:
Have you taken a look at : https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK-ROS ? They support the Matrice 100. depending on the differences m100 and m200 this might work for you

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-10-19**:
Use DJI's onboard SDK as @Mickboe1 mentioned. If you want to use DJI's simulator you'll either need another computer (alongside your linux computer) with Windows/Mac installed. Or you can do it with virtual machines as well with some network hacks.

**Comment by [kotoko](https://answers.ros.org/users/27417/kotoko/) on 2017-10-19**:
@Mickboe1 & @l4ncelot, sorry I probably made the question too vague. I know about the existence of both the SDK and the ROS node, I have doubts about the stability since it is quite new.

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-10-19**:
I've been working a while ago with old SDK and it was painful. Lot of bugs I had to fix etc. But I've seen that their documentation is much better now. They also reworked the whole SDK so it's cleaner than before. But I've not tested it yet.

**Comment by [kotoko](https://answers.ros.org/users/27417/kotoko/) on 2017-10-19**:
Thank you so much! Which model did you use? Did you integrate with Gazebo? Can you make an answer so I can accept it and/or not use the comment as chat XD?

**Comment by [Femer](https://answers.ros.org/users/26134/femer/) on 2017-10-19**:
Hi, have also a look at this fork: [ASL ETH DJI](https://github.com/ethz-asl/dji_onboard_sdk_ros/wiki/Introduction).

**Comment by [kotoko](https://answers.ros.org/users/27417/kotoko/) on 2017-10-19**:
@Femer Thank you for that contribution. I hadn't found it yet. Have you tried it yet? The project seems to have ended in 2016 and version 3.2 of the SDK (which is now in version 3.3). Also, it is dedicated to MAtrice 100 (which is not big enough for my payload). Do you think it is still worth it?

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-10-20**:
@kotoko you should use the newest version of firmware. I think DJI won't let you fly with outdated firmware. The integration with Gazebo is not officially supported. But have a look at this [repo](https://github.com/caochao39/hku_m100_gazebo). It has the matrice 100 simulated in Gazebo.

**Comment by [kotoko](https://answers.ros.org/users/27417/kotoko/) on 2017-10-20**:
@l4ncelot yeah I saw it. I'm a bit reluctant to adopt DJI - just got an e-mail from a developer at DJI asking me what Gazebo was... I will probably not be able to fly the latest firmware because I will use an M600 that has a [documented issue on the latest firmware](http://forum.dev.dji.com)

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-10-20**:
Well it's not a big surprise he didn't know what Gazebo is. In DJI there's very small team working on ROS SDK.

**Comment by [Femer](https://answers.ros.org/users/26134/femer/) on 2017-10-20**:
@kotoko what do you mean the project seems to have ended? I know people that regularly use that repo and fly with DJI ;)

For ROS simulations I'd suggest this other package: rotors.

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-10-20**:
@Femer yeah, the [rotors](https://github.com/ethz-asl/rotors_simulator) package is useful, but it doesn't contain any DJI models as I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To summarize all the comments here.

DJI has ROS related onboard SDK [here](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK-ROS). The lastest version 3.3 has improved in many ways including better documentation. Before it was just mess.

The DJI's simulation supports only Windows/Mac. So to try it out one need either another Windows/Mac computer connected to autopilot or virtual machine. DJI ROS onboard SDK will run classically on Linux system.

Here's a git [repo](https://github.com/caochao39/hku_m100_gazebo) which integrates DJI copter in Gazebo (matrice 100).

I wouldn't recommend using outdated DJI firmware because DJI won't let you fly with one.

---

Originally posted by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) with karma: 826 on 2017-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kotoko](https://answers.ros.org/users/27417/kotoko/) on 2017-10-20**:
Thanks! Only would like to add that, for the M600, the firmware constraint competes with [a bug on the firmware](http://forum.dev.dji.com/thread-33101-1-1.html) && examples of  [M600+LIDAR+ROS](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/modules/collision-avoidance/collision-avoidance.html)